# Google Pay option doesn't show up - Stripe integration with react native

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments, google-pay

I am trying to setup Stripe payments on my React native app by following Stripe's mobile element.
When I click on 'CHeckout', I see card details but don't see Google Pay as an option.
Here is the code snippet:

```
const { error, paymentOption } = await initPaymentSheet({
        merchantDisplayName: "Example, Inc",
        customerId: customer,
        customerEphemeralKeySecret: ephemeralKey,
        paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntent,
        // Set `allowsDelayedPaymentMethods` to true if your business can handle payment
        //methods that complete payment after a delay, like SEPA Debit and Sofort.
        allowsDelayedPaymentMethods: true,

        defaultBillingDetails: {
          name: 'Jane Doe',
        },
        googlePay: {
          merchantCountryCode: 'US',
          testEnv: true, // use test environment
          currencyCode: 'USD',
        },
      });
```

I added the following in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled"
android:value="true" />
```

app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
 implementation("com.stripe:stripe-android:20.36.1")
 implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:19.3.0-beta01")
}
```

Added google and maven to buildscript and allprojectsbuild.gradle:

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
  }
}
```

Even though I enabled test mode, I installed Google Pay and set it up too.
I still dont see Google pay, when i checkout. It shows me an option only to enter card details and nothing else.
What am I missing?